# Can I run Windows Phone 8 emulator (hyper-v) under an os in virtualbox/vmware?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-phone

My computer has Windows 8.1 Single Language, but I need at least Pro to enable Hyper-V. I have a Windows Embedded 8.1 Industrial Pro ISO and a Dreamspark key, but I have all my data on my hard drive so I don't want to format/upgrade (no upgrade because it's risky).

Will that work ? I have a i5 CPU that supports hardware virtualization.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the fast answer, I'll install it now.

Comment: And by the way, if it takes hours then there's a problem (hardware virtualization disabled/not working). From my experience a Windows 7 install in a VM takes 20 minutes, Windows 8 may take even less.

Comment: My old computer was a total garbage. It used to take 1-2 hours. Visual studio was even more... I hope this one will be faster...

Comment: It probably didn't support HW virtualization and falled back to software virtualization which is bloody slow.

Comment: It did. Lol. I used to use emulator on it :P But it had celeron. 1,2 ghz lol.

Comment: not opening, but installing. (I'll make this one a chat.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was wrong in my comment about it working.

Yes, the Windows 8 itself will install and work just fine, but you won't be able to start another hypervisor in it, because VirtualBox doesn't [yet](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) support [nested virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_virtualization) which is required to start a virtual machine inside another one, and the Windows Phone emulator appears to be a VM running on Hyper-V.

In your case the best solution is to install your Windows 8 copy on your computer itself, or to try other virtualization solutions such as VMware which support nested virtualization (I don't know if the trial version support it though).